# Grant read access using for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

QUERY

BEGIN

```
FOR R IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'ONAME')

LOOP

    GRANT SELECT ON R.TABLE_NAME TO UNAME;

END LOOP;
```

END;
/

I want to grant read access of tables in ONAME to UNAME. But, I've the following errors:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "GRANT" when expecting one of the following:
( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
raise return select update while with 
  <<
continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, you can't do any DDL statements directly in PL/SQL. You have to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to execute them, e.g.:

```
FOR R IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'ONAME')
LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON '||R.TABLE_NAME||' TO UNAME';
END LOOP;
```